# How can I link Voronoi projection points back to original metadata use to create projection?

Tags: r, projection, voronoi

I'm using the `deldir` package to calculate the Voronoi projection of a set of coordinates.

This working great, and I've been able to construct the plot, but I need to relate the calculated points back to the original data set that has additional metadata for each coordinate pair.

Basically, I need a polygon ID that I can match back to my original data. So for example if coordinate pair #1 is projected as a five-sided polygon, I need to assign polygon ID = 1 to each of those five line segments so I can merge in the metadata.

Example with dummy data:

```
require(deldir)

set.seed(21)

x <- rnorm(500, 0, 1.5)
y <- rnorm(500, 0, 1)

df1 <- data.frame(x,y,ID=seq(1,500,1))

vtess <- deldir(df1$x, df1$y)
```

So for `df1[1,]`, I need to know every value that was generated in `vtess`.

The ID for `df1[1,]` = 1, so I'm trying to create a column where `vtess$polygonID` = 1 for every segment generated by `df1[1,]` and so on.

Any help would be fantastic

Comment: So, you're looking for `vtess$dirsgs[, c("ind1", "ind2")]`? You're phrasing seems a little confused because a segment is generated by a *pair* of points, not to a single point. Also, you refer to `vtess` like a single data frame, but it is a list with several items, of which it sounds like you want the `dirsgs` data frame?

Comment: @Gregor Correct that I mean each pair of points, and that (I think) I'm interested in the `$dirsgs` data frame. Does `ind1` and `ind2` reference the `df1` x or y point?

Comment: It references the row number of the input data, so in your case the `ID`. `ind1` is the row number of the point on one side of the segment, `ind2` is the row number of the point on the other side.

Comment: @Gregor Got it. That makes sense now, so thanks for that, but now I'm less sure about the solution I'm looking for. What I'm really trying to do is connect the area of each polygon to the metadata associated with the point that it (the polygon) contains. Any thoughts on how to approach that? In simple terms, if the point A is blue, how can I make polygon A blue.

Comment: @Gregor that's what I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit old, but I did a project that used `deldir` and modified the plotting method to color certain polygons. I can't remember if I updated since `deldir` switched from matrix to data frame, but taking a look might be helpful: https://github.com/gregorp/rlandscape

Comment: But I would strongly recommend running a *small* example to see what's going on. `n = 500` is big. Use `n = 10`, and go through `?deldir` and the resulting object to see what's there. The `summary` data frame is very useful and has the areas. The `dirsgs` has all the segments data...